# How do I define sources in base.gwt.xml?

Tags: gwt, configuration

I'm working on a project with different entry-points, each defined by a .gwt.xml file.

In every single file we import the sources, but I would like them to be defined in base.gwt.xml (which every configuration file already includes).

I tried to move the sources definition but then the compilation fails.
I also tried to change the source path to something like "/ui/packageName" or "./ui/packageName" but I just get more warnings.

What is the correct way to import sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Example of module definitions]

This is an example of multiple modules I have at work. Each `module.gwt.xml` has paths **that are relative to its location**:

Our `gwt` module has code that uses only GWT libs (widgets, code that uses `GWT.create()`, etc.). The only thing it inherits is `com.google.gwt.user.User`.

It has the following source declarations:

- `<source path="client" />`
- `<source path="shared" />`

It also has a public_html path:

- `<public path="public_html" />`

We want the `Common` module to have access to the code of our `GWT` module, so inside `Common.gwt.xml`, we have: `<inherits name='com.ourcompany.gwt.GWT' />`.

We want the `user` module to have access to the code of our `GWT` and `Common` modules, so inside `User.gwt.xml`, we have `<inherits name="com.ourcompany.common.Common" />`.

Since `Common` already inherits `GWT`, we have code from both modules available by just inheriting the `Common` module.

That is the proper way to inherit modules (import sources).

Comment: quite a nice answer !

Comment: So my problem is that base.gwt.xml is (dunno why) in an other package, hence unable to see the packages I want to import.

Thanks for the asnwer.

Comment: @algiogia Yeah, just declare source paths only within each module, and use `<inherits...` statements to use that code in other modules. Beware that if you make a parent module reference code in a child module, you will get source not found exceptions at GWT compile time.